# I am geting checkbox items checked after collapsing the Grid and click again to visible the grid

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I am getting ID from database in event handler.

```
private void buttonAddRooms_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        EditRoomsDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        AddRoomsDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        Room room = new Room();
        RoomFactory fac = new RoomFactory();
        room.Room_ID = fac.RoomID();
        txtRoomID.Text = room.Room_ID.ToString();
        //COBbadspace.SelectedItem = -1;
 }
```

as button savedclick all the values from the form once inserted into the data base but again when i click addroombutton to visible the grid all the last checked items show checked so i want a way that when i click addroombutton to visible grid all the checkboxes unchecked and textboxes cleared/empty because as i click again to visible grid all the values still there. clbfacilities is a checklist box containing comboboxItems.

```
private void btnSaveRoom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Room room = new Room();
        RoomFactory fac=new RoomFactory();
        room.RoomType = COBbadspace.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
       // room.RoomType = txtbadsapace.Text;

        foreach (var item in clbFacilities.SelectedItems)
        {
            room.RoomFacilities += (item as ComboBoxItem).Content + ",";
        }
        String price = txtRoomPrice.Text;
        room.Room_Price = Convert.ToInt32(price);
        if (rbAvailable.IsChecked ?? false)
            room.Room_Status = true;
        else
            room.Room_Status = false;
        if (fac.Insert(room))

         {
            MessageBox.Show("insert");

         }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("not insert");

        AddRoomsDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        EditRoomsDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        viewRoomsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question with some screenshots? I'm having a hard time reading / fully understanding your question due to your long sentences and sometimes wrong use of words (to visible -> to visualize, ...).

Comment: actually i am using grid visible and collapsed to show and hide the grid as i click add room button to visible the grid, grid contain  textbox and checklistbox control as i click save button that grid collapsed and again i click button to visible grid all last inserted text and check checkboxes in checklistbox still there

Answer (score 0):

**Write a function that clears all your checkboxes and texboxex.**

```
private void CleanRoomGui()
{
chBx1.isChecked = false;
chBx2.isChecked = false;
txtRoomID.Text = String.Empty;
txtRoomName.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

This is my answer because I dont know how you design looks like.

If you got a window with the checkboxes and textboxes you could load this window new, when you do this the default values will be uses.

```
private void GetRoomDetails()
{
    var roomDetails = new Details();
    if(roomDetails.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK)
    {            
        txtRoomID.Text = roomDetails.Room_ID.ToString();
    } 
}
```